# How do I dynamically define an index using an existing select query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use `IsNull()` to return the current variable value, but I receive an undefined `Index error`. The issue is that the query returns a full `array`.

How do I go about assigning a specific `memberID` so `IsNull()` will return the information already in the DB back into the query, thus stopping the query from erasing my current field data.

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {

    switch (true) {
        //Removed other case for brevity

        case isset($_POST['update']):
            if($_POST['name'] != "") {
                $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        } 
            else {
                $name = NULL;
        }

        if($_POST['designation'] != "") {
                $designation = trim($_POST['designation']);
        } 
            else {
                $designation = NULL;
        }

        if($_POST['rank'] != "") {
                $rank = trim($_POST['rank']);
        } 
            else {
                $rank = NULL;
        }

        if($_POST['currentScore'] != "") {
                $currentScore = trim($_POST['currentScore']);
        } 
            else {
                $currentScore = NULL;
        }
            if(!is_null($name) || !is_null($designation) || !is_null($rank) || !is_null($currentScore)) {
            $update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE members SET name = IsNull(?, name), designation = IsNull(?, designation), rank = IsNull(?, rank), currentScore = IsNull(?, currentScore)  WHERE memberID = ? ");//Prepared statements are immune to sql injection, so they are used for security
            $update->bind_param('ssiii', $name, $designation, $rank, $currentScore, $memberID);// Binding the values to use in the prepared statement
                if($update->execute()) {
                        header('location: index.php');
                        die();
                    } 
            }
        break;

//      case isset($_POST['delete']):
//          // Delete statement goes here
//      break;
    }
}
if($results = $conn->query("SELECT *, ((previousScore + currentScore) / 2) AS avgScore FROM members")) {
FROM members")) {
    if($results->num_rows) {
        while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
            $records[] = $row; //Appending value to array
        }
        $results->free();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code should work in theory. What happens when you run it?

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving? `Undefined designation index`? This is strange `) { FROM members")) {`..

Comment: @GolezTrol I apologize for the delay, I was called away.  *Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in* c:\\-path-, is the exact error.

Comment: @RyanVincent I will try that code and see what it returns.

Comment: @RyanVincent I get `NULL string(48) "C:\\-path-\controller.php34"` with the line update being the only change at each point, and an additional error of: `Undefined variable: designation in C:\\-path- on line 34` when placing the error check code before the `if (is_null ..)`

Comment: @RyanVincent That part of the code works, I don't understand where the syntax error would be.

Comment: The error you mentioned to me suggests that `$conn->prepare` returned false, which means there was an error during preparing itself. Find out what that error is (probably using `$conn->error`), and work from there.